# Trigger a curl command during Kubernetes scale

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have an application that uses an install token that is required for each new install (token can't be used more than once). I have an api I created that I can curl to, that will recreate my `secret.yaml` file with a new install token when I run it.

Is there a way to trigger the curl command to execute when I run

```
kubectl scale deployment --replicas=x
```

so that the `secret.yaml` will update before it creates the new pod?

I know I can run a cronjob every minute, but I would like for this to be able to autoscale eventually, so it would be ideal if I could get the secret file updated just before the new pods are created from the deployment yaml.

Comment: what about doing that in init-container?

Comment: I think that will work actually, didn't even think about that, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since @Lei Yang has already proposed a solution to this issue, I decided to provide a Community Wiki answer just for better visibility to other community members.

Using [init containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) is a good way to trigger the `curl` command every time a Deployment is scaled. As described in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) - init containers can contain utilities or setup scripts not present in an app image.

---

I've create a simple example to illustrate how init containers can work with the `curl` command.

First, I created an `app-1` Deployment which contains an `init-curl` init container:
**NOTE:** I used the [curlimages/curl](https://hub.docker.com/r/curlimages/curl) image, it's the official curl image generated by the curl docker team.

```
$ cat app-1.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: app-1
  name: app-1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-1
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: init-curl
        image: curlimages/curl
        command: ['sh', '-c', 'curl example.com']
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
```

After creating the Deployment we can check if the `init-curl` works correctly:

```
$ kubectl apply -f app-1.yaml
deployment.apps/app-1 created

$ kubectl get pods | grep app-1
app-1-f6d7cdd68-hfp78                                    1/1     Running   0          12s

$ kubectl logs -f app-1-f6d7cdd68-hfp78 init-curl
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>
...
```

Now let's try to scale the `app-1` Deployment:

```
$ kubectl scale deployment app-1 --replicas=2
deployment.apps/app-1 scaled

$ kubectl get pods | grep app-1
app-1-f6d7cdd68-hfp78                                    1/1     Running   0          6m1s
app-1-f6d7cdd68-wbchx                                    1/1     Running   0          5s

$ kubectl logs -f app-1-f6d7cdd68-wbchx init-curl
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1256  100  1256    0     0   2043      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2042
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>
...
```

As we can see it works as expected, the `curl` command is executed every time the Deployment is scaled.